# Johnson Counter Syntax error. Unexpected token: generate

Tags: logic, verilog, system-verilog

My college teacher asked for me to implement a Johnson Counter and it's test bench, with an width<=32 (he calls it an N parameter), and the implementation has to use `generate/for` structures. Although I had learned a little about Johnson Counter, I don't know how to use `generate` in this case, and I had some errors when I tried to run the test bench. Here is my implementation so far:

```
module johnsonCounter #(parameter N = 32)  
  ( 
    input clk,                
    input rstn,
    output reg [N-1:0] out
  );    

  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (!rstn)
      out <= 1;
    else begin
      out[N-1] <= ~out[0];
      generate
        for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i=i+1) begin
          out[i] <= out[i+1];
        end
      endgenerate

    end
  end
endmodule
```

Here is the test bench:

```
module tb;
  parameter N = 32;
  
  reg clk;
  reg rstn;
  wire [N-1:0] out;
  
  johnsonCounter    u0 (.clk (clk),
                .rstn (rstn),
                .out (out));
  
  always #10 clk = ~clk;
  
  initial begin
    {clk, rstn} <= 0;

    $monitor ("T=%0t out=%b", $time, out);
    repeat (2) @(posedge clk);
    rstn <= 1;
    repeat (15) @(posedge clk);
    $finish;
  end
  
  initial begin
    $dumpvars;
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
  end
endmodule
```

These are the errors:

```
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: generate[_GENERATE]. This is a Verilog keyword since IEEE Std 1364-2001 and cannot be used as an identifier. Use -v95 argument for compilation." "design.sv" 13  7
ERROR VCP2020 "begin...end pair(s) mismatch detected. 2 <end> tokens are missing." "design.sv" 17  7
ERROR VCP2020 "module/macromodule...endmodule pair(s) mismatch detected. 1 <endmodule> tokens are missing." "design.sv" 17  7
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: endgenerate[_ENDGENERATE]. This is a Verilog keyword since IEEE Std 1364-2001 and cannot be used as an identifier. Use -v95 argument for compilation." "design.sv" 17  7
```

Any help is welcome =)

Answer (score 1):

It is illegal to use `generate` in that way.

For your code, just a `for` loop is needed (without `generate`):

```
  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (!rstn)
      out <= 1;
    else begin
      out[N-1] <= ~out[0];
      for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i=i+1) begin
          out[i] <= out[i+1];
      end
    end
  end
```

For `generate` syntax, refer to the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 27. *Generate constructs*.

Answer (score -1):

I tried implementing it using the `generate` construct. I am also new at this, so if anybody sees any problem or error, or could provide any suggestion to improve performance, I would appreciate it.

Regarding your question, I always use `generate` to instantiate several modules, I think it makes my code cleaner and easier to understand. So what I did is to define a simple D flip-flop module, which I will use to instantiate it. If you want to use `generate`, you have to define an iterative variable with `genvar`. Also, you should use `generate` outside an always block (I don't know if there is a situation where you could use it inside the always block). Below, you can see the code.

```
module ff 
  (
    input clk,
    input rstn,
    input d,
    output reg q,
    output reg qn
  );
  
  always @(posedge clk)
    begin
      if(!rstn)
        begin
          q <= 0;
          qn <= 1;
        end
      else
        begin
          q <= d;
          qn <= ~d;
        end
    end
endmodule

module johnsonCounter #(parameter N = 4)  
  ( 
    input clk,                
    input rstn,
    output [N-1:0] out,
    output [N-1:0] nout
  );    

  genvar i;
  generate
    for (i = 0; i < N-1; i=i+1) begin
      ff flip (.clk(clk), .rstn(rstn), .d(out[i+1]), .q(out[i]), .qn(nout[i]));
    end
  endgenerate
  
  ff lastFlip (.clk(clk), .rstn(clk), .d(nout[0]), .q(out[N-1]), .qn(nout[N-1]));
endmodule
```

Here you have the testbench, too. One thing I changed from your code is the `dumpfile` line. It should go before `dumpvar`.

```
module tb;
  parameter N = 4;
  
  reg clk;
  reg rstn;
  wire [N-1:0] out;
  
  johnsonCounter    u0 (.clk (clk),
                .rstn (rstn),
                .out (out));
  
  always #10 clk = ~clk;
  
  initial begin
    {clk, rstn} <= 0;

    $monitor ("T=%0t out=%b", $time, out);
    repeat (2) @(posedge clk);
    rstn <= 1;
    repeat (15) @(posedge clk);
    $finish;
  end
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
  end
endmodule
```

This code was tested using *EDA Playground* and it worked fine but, as I said, I am not an expert, so if anybody finds any error or have any suggestion, it is welcome.